# Maximum Depth exceeded in my CartIcon component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use a cart icon to dynamically display the number of items in cart anytime user adds a new item. But I am getting a 'Maximum depth exceeded error'.
I am using useEffect to listen to changes in the items in cart by setting the state to the items and putting items as a dependency array in the cart icon component.
I did this because
`window.addEventListener('storage', cartTotal)`
doesn't work.

Here is my cart icon component

```
const CartIcon = ({ fill, className }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
    cartTotal();
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="cart-icon">
      <svg
        width="2.5em"
        height="2.5em"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        className="bi bi-bag cart"
        fill={fill}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          fillRule="evenodd"
          d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-2.5 2.5V4h5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5v9a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5H2z"
        />
      </svg>
      <span className={className}>{cartTotal()}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartIcon;
```

getCart function is used to get the items in the cart from localStorage, and cartTotal is a function to get the number of items in the cart. Here are their codes.

```
//Get the items in the cart
export const getCart = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
  }
  return [];
};


//Get total number of items in the cart
export const cartTotal = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).length;
    }
  }
  return 0;
};
```

***UPDATE: So I should have included that the CartIcon component is displayed the navbar which is only mounts once through out the application (apart from in /signin and /signout paths). So setting an empty array would mean useEffect will almost never run again throughout the application. This way, the number of items in the CartIcon does not change until I refresh. The 'Add to Cart' button is also in a different component. LocalStorage is the only way the CartIcon can know how many items are in the cart.

Comment: Are you sure in your code there is no infinite loop?

Comment: These kinds of errors only occur when there is infinite loop, or the function is executed on each render which in turn re-render the component.

Comment: Yes, the loop is caused because I set `items` as the dependency array. Somehow that causes useEffect to keep running.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. Now i hope you know the solution after know cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `cart` inside `useEffect` as well as subscribing to it's changes, which ends up with an infinite loop. Remove `cart` from the dependency array, so it gets called only once, at component mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setItems(getCart());
}, []);
```

Also you don't have to use `cartTotal` function. You can rely on state.

```
<span className={className}>{items.length}</span>
```

**Note**: Remember to set an initial value for items in state.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Comment: So I should have included that the CartIcon component is displayed the navbar which is only mounts once through out the application (apart from in /signin and /signout paths).

So setting an empty array would mean useEffect will almost never run again throughout the application. This way, the number of items in the CartIcon does not change until I refresh.
The Add to Cart button is also in a different component. LocalStorage is the only way the CartIcon can know how many items are in the cart.

Comment: @DavidQuartey But you can't listen to local storage changes directly, at least by using `useEffect`. Its completely up to you how and when would you like to save data from storage inside your application, but saving it with every render isnt the best idea. I have shown you imo best option, to get the data from storage only once, when application starts, then use it for your logic needs and update the data inside storage in specified cases, e.g. unmounting component, clicking some button etc.

Comment: being an ecommerce application, the data in the storage only gets set when the user adds their first product to the cart. And throughout the user's session, they may add or delete items severally. I tried the method you said but It didn't work. Is it possible to only read the data once and still get the dynamic cart-icon effect?